# Another way to calculate monotonicity of a sequence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Is there another way to determine monotonicity besides $U_{n+1} - U_n$?

Comment: U_{n+1} / U_n.  More generally, you can compose U_n with any increasing function (this preserves monotonicity), then test the monotonicity of the new sequence.

Comment: (I'm in a silly mood, sorry) I find most sequences very dull, so for me the test would be $P(U_n$ is monotonous $) = 1$ almost always.

Comment: Andrew is funny, but I'd lower the probability to $1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is exceedingly tiny. In any event, it's "monotonicity".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write something so this question doesn't remain unanswered.

Sometimes it can be quite difficult to prove that a sequence is increasing.  For example, Smetaniuk gave a proof that the number of Latin squares $L_n$ (Sloane's [A002860](https://oeis.org/A002860)) is increasing (actually, he proved $L_{n+1} \geq (n+1)!L_n$), which is one of the best results around regarding the mysterious $L_n$.

Smetaniuk, Bohdan
A new construction of Latin squares. II. The number of Latin squares is strictly increasing. 
Ars Combin. 14 (1982), 131–145.